# Will Google Analytics overwrite UID with CID?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Using Measurement Protocol and setting up my own Google Analytics reporting.

I had previously used only UID to identify users who authenticated with us, ignoring "anonymous" users. Not the best idea. Now I want to add the CID field because I do want to capture all users and any events that occur prior to authentication.

If I start providing CID in addition to UID, will GA consider that a brand new user?  Right now it has automatically used the UID to be the "Client ID" in the User Explorer section.

The User ID documentation indicates I could create a new unified user ID view to "merge" these records, but I don't really want to do that because I don't want my core user base to be duplicates.

A solution I thought would be to do something complicated like

```
var props = {uid: 1234};
if (uid) {
   cid: uid
} else {
   cid: getTheCID()
}
```

If we only have a `uid` turn it into a `cid` and then all other users, get a new CID.